# Look for substring in a string with at most one different character-javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new in programing and right now I am working on one program. Program need to find the substring in a string and return the index where the chain starts to be the same. I know that for that I can use "indexOf". Is not so easy. I want to find out substrings with at moste one different char.
I was thinking about regular expresion... but not really know how to use it because I need to use regular expresion for every element of the string. Here some code wich propably will clarify what I want to do:

```
var A= "abbab"; 
var B= "ba";
var tb=[];

console.log(A.indexOf(B));

  for (var i=0;i<B.length; i++){
    var D=B.replace(B[i],"[a-z]");
    tb.push(A.indexOf(D));        
  }
console.log(tb);
```

I know that the substring B and string A are the lowercase letters. Will be nice to get any advice how to make it using regular expresions. Thx

```
Simple Input:
A B
1) abbab ba
2) hello world
3) banana nan
Expected Output:
1) 1 2
2) No Match!
3) 0 2
```

Comment: please add the information to the question.

Comment: *output:1 2* - still unclear. How's `ba` is matched here `abbab ba` at `1` and `2` indexes

Comment: please explain *I want to find out substrings with at moste one different char.*

Comment: it means that the substring not need to be exactly te same as a sample but can be differen with at mose one char I hope an example help you to get it

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: one letter can be different in substring. In this case ba we will find on index 2 but if we gonna replace "a" in ba with b we will find also bb at index 1 as needed substring.

Comment: `3) banana nan` -> `3) 0 2`. By this logic it should be `0 2 4 7`

Comment: I think the title should say "character" instead of "charter".

Answer (score 0):

While probably theoretically possible, I think it would very complicated to try this kind of search while attempting to incorporate all possible search query options in one long complex regular expression. I think a better approach is to use JavaScript to dynamically create various simpler options and then search with each separately.

The following code sequentially replaces each character in the initial query string with a regular expression wild card (i.e. a period, '.') and then searches the target string with that. For example, if the initial query string is 'nan', it will search with '.an', 'n.n' and 'na.'. It will only add the position of the hit to the list of hits if that position has not already been hit on a previous search. i.e. It ensures that the list of hits contains only unique values, even if multiple query variations found a hit at the same location. *(This could be implemented even better with ES6 sets, but I couldn't get the Stack Overflow code snippet tool to cooperate with me while trying to use a set, even with the Babel option checked.)* Finally, it sorts the hits in ascending order.

Update: The search algorithm has been updated/corrected. Originally, some hits were missed because the `exec` search for any query variation would only iterate as per the JavaScript default, i.e. after finding a match, it would start the next search at the next character after the *end* of the previous match, e.g. it would find 'aa' in 'aaaa' at positions 0 and 2. Now it starts the next search at the next character after the *start* of the previous match, e.g. it now finds 'aa' in 'aaaa' at positions 0, 1 and 2.

```js
const findAllowingOneMismatch = (target, query) => {
  const numLetters = query.length;
  const queryVariations = [];
  for (let variationNum = 0; variationNum < numLetters; variationNum += 1) {
    queryVariations.push(query.slice(0, variationNum) + "." + query.slice(variationNum + 1));
  };
  let hits = [];
  queryVariations.forEach(queryVariation => {
    const re = new RegExp(queryVariation, "g");
    let myArray;
    while ((searchResult = re.exec(target)) !== null) {
      re.lastIndex = searchResult.index + 1;
      const hit = searchResult.index;
      // console.log('found a hit with ' + queryVariation + ' at position ' + hit);
      if (hits.indexOf(hit) === -1) {
        hits.push(searchResult.index);
      }
    }
  });
  hits = hits.sort((a,b)=>(a-b));
  console.log('Found "' + query + '" in "' + target + '" at positions:', JSON.stringify(hits));
};

[
  ['abbab', 'ba'],
  ['hello', 'world'],
  ['banana', 'nan'],
  ['abcde abcxe abxxe xbcde', 'abcd'],
  ['--xx-xxx--x----x-x-xxx--x--x-x-xx-', '----']
].forEach(pair => {findAllowingOneMismatch(pair[0], pair[1])});
```